# Debugging a firmware ported on a silicon implementation of RISC V TinyConfig

Tags: debugging, ide, boot, riscv

I have a plan to tape-out a Z-scale (TinyConfig) version of Rocket chip in an attempt to replace MSP430 that is running with a bluetooth module for a mobile medical system. I have seen in one of the RISC V material (Untethering the Rocket-Chip Producing a stand-alone lowRISC SoC) that Rocket Chip is not a standalone system and doesn't support a direct bootloading. But also, after exploring the RocketChip directory and generating the TinyConfig verilog, I realized that there is a bootrom and Jtag implementation. 
So I was wondering whether the Z-scale (TinyConfig) version can run as a standalone system ?
Is there any IDE (like CCS for MSP430) that has been tried to port and debug a firmware on a silicon implementation of RISC V TinyConfig ? and if it's possible to debug in real-time by setting breakpoints ?

Thank you